# Android Maps V2 API: Authentication Failure for some users, but not all

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, maps, android-maps-v2

I'm having an issue with the Android Maps V2 displaying a blank screen for SOME of my users. I have nearly 100K users using my app, but there is a small percentage that complain they can not see the app (blank) no matter what they do. I have had them restart the app and clear Google Play Store data in hopes that it'll work.

I have looked at the logs(snippet below) and see the classic "Authorization Failure". At first I thought that perhaps the user did not have a valid internet connection, but I'm checking that they are online, plus they make web calls which do work. I also suspected that they did not have Google Play Services installed/enabled, but they also do.

Questions:
1. Is there a problem using the Android Maps V2 API in other countries that I do not know about?
2. I suspected at one point that these users have a proxy in place, does Google prevent downloading the map under those conditions?
3. I do see "04-06 14:57:19.804 E/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 7295): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included." in the logs as well, but I have read in several locations to ignore this error. Should I look more into that?
3. I'm fresh out of ideas, any other recommendations?

04-06 14:57:18.359 D/MainActivity( 7295): isOnline() Device is connected
04-06 14:57:18.364 D/MainActivity( 7295): Google Play Services available
04-06 14:57:18.384 D/dalvikvm( 7295): DexOpt: --- BEGIN 'ads-1950455566.jar' (bootstrap=0) ---
04-06 14:57:18.409 E/Google Maps Android API( 7295): Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.
04-06 14:57:18.409 E/Google Maps Android API( 7295): Ensure that the following correspond to what is in the API Console: Package Name: MY_PACKAGE, API Key: , Certificate Fingerprint: 
04-06 14:57:18.419 I/Google Maps Android API( 7295): Failed to contact Google servers. Another attempt will be made when connectivity is established.

Comment: Ever get anywhere with this error? I am having the same issues with a very small number of my users, with no luck. Any help appreciated.